# Php Searchable Email Archive

Tags: php, email, imap, archive

I manage a club website. They use an email discussion list service that does not provide an archive.  I have been playing around with several different ways to use php imap to collect email, extract the subject and body, then put them into a mysql database, where they can be pulled into the website where they can be read by members.

While this is easy enough to implement using some of the pre-made email to database classes around the net, they would also like the archive to be searchable, emails grouped into "discussions", and easily be able to delete/moderate the entries.  This seems like it would take a ton of work, and I am hoping someone has already done something like this or that I have overlooked some software that already contains this functionality.  I would hate to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html)

Comment: Thanks I have a look, and give it a go around in the next few days.